# How remove all row and col names from apply result

Tags: r

```
a=c(1,2,3,4)
b=c(11,10,7,8)
z=data.frame(a,b)
```

I found median as follows , but I want to get back just value of median without any row or col name .

```
apply(z[1], 2, median)

 ## a 
## 2.5
```

however I used `unnmae` but it get me this `[1]` but I need just value of median i mean just `2.5`

```
unname(apply(z[1], 2, median))
##[1] 2.5
```

Comment: You could do `cat(sapply(z, median))` for all medians or `cat(median(z[,1]))` for only the first column.

Comment: What do you need to do with this number, knowing this might help.  The `unname` code gives you a vector of length 1 with no names.  The `[1]` is part of how it is displayed.

Comment: Is the question about printing an undecorated value or how to get a scalar return value? If the latter, note that there is no such thing in R. Values like 2.5 are length 1 vectors: `length(2.5) == 1`, `2.5[1] == 2.5`, `2.5[1][1] == 2.5[1]`, etc.

Comment: thanks for your help